# Bad Request, Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand - Qt Websocket Server

Tags: c++, qt, websocket, server

I have two questions about this issue. 
First of all I'm trying to get the following code working

```
socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    // I'm a little confused as to why we're connecting on port 80 
    // when my goal is to listen just on port 3000. Shouldn't I just 
    // need to connect straight to port 3000?
    socket->connectToHost("localhost", 80);

    if (socket->waitForConnected(3000))
    {
        qDebug() << "Connected!";

        // send
        socket->write("hello server\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n");
        socket->waitForBytesWritten(1000);
        socket->waitForReadyRead(3000);
        qDebug() << "Reading: " << socket->bytesAvailable();

        qDebug() << socket->readAll();

        socket->close();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Not connected!";
    }
```

But this is the error that I get:

```
"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>400 Bad Request</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Bad `Request</h1>\n<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />\n</p>\n<hr>\n<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80</address>\n</body></html>\n"`
```

Has anyone got any ideas about this?

Second question is: I'm trying to get a c++/Qt server working similar to a node js server. So I'm wanting to be able to access the connection requests in the browser. So when someone connects to site:3000 I will be able to catch the request and display some content. Can it be achieved with a `QTcpSocket` server? If so then how could I implement something like :

```
// I know this isn't valid c++, Just to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve 
socket.on(Request $request) {
    if ($request.method() == 'GET') {

    }
}
```

If this is achievable is there much speed gains in comparison to doing this in nodejs?
I'm personally trying to avoid js as much as possible.

if i comment the code then I can get a running program but when I try to connect on port 8000 from the browser nothing happens (just a 404 error)

updated answer:

header file:

```
#ifndef SOCKETTEST_H
#define SOCKETTEST_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

class SocketTest : public QTcpServer
{
public:
    SocketTest(QObject *parent);

private:
    QTcpSocket *client;

public slots:
    void startServer(int port);
    void readyToRead(void);
    void incomingConnection(int socket);
};

#endif // SOCKETTEST_H
```

.cpp file

```
#include "sockettest.h"

SocketTest::SocketTest(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
    this->startServer(8000);
}

void SocketTest::startServer(int port)
{
    bool success = listen(QHostAddress::Any, port); // this starts the server listening on your port
    // handle errors
}

void SocketTest::incomingConnection(int socket)
{
    // a client has made a connection to your server
    QTcpSocket *client = new QTcpSocket(this);
    //client->setSocketDescription(socket);

    // these two lines are important, they will direct traffic from the client
    // socket to your handlers in this object

    connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readToRead()));
    connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnect()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));

}

void SocketTest::readyToRead(void)
{
    QTcpSocket *client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();


    qDebug() << "Just got a connection";

    // you can process requests differently here. this example
    // assumes that you have line breaks in text requests

    while (client->canReadLine())
    {
        QString aLine = QString::fromUtf8(client->readLine()).trimmed();

        // Process your request here, parse the text etc
    }
}

// this gives me the following error 
// /user_data/projects/qt/QtServer/sockettest.cpp:47: error: no ‘void 
// SocketTest::disconnected()’ member function declared in class ‘SocketTest’
 void SocketTest::disconnected()
                               ^
void SocketTest::disconnected()
{
    // jsut a qu, wont all these * vars lead to a memory leak? and shouldn't I be using a var Qtc... *client; in the header file?
    QTcpSocket *client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();

    // clean up a disconnected user
}
```

Comment: 1. If your server is listening on port 3000 then yes, connect to 3000 and not to 80. 2. For communication via http take a look at [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html). Because a communication through TCP-sockets is lower abstraction than HTTP-protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Here with [`waitForConnected`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected), you are connecting on port 80, and waiting 3000ms maximum for the "connected state", i.e. not connecting on port 3000 at all. This is the blocking way of waiting for a connection to be established, instead of connecting to the `QTcpSocket::connected` signal.
2. Like Yuriy pointed out, `QNetworkAccessManager` is way more convenient to handle HTTP requests as a client. As in your example, you created a TCP client, and not a server
3. Yes you can build an web server with Qt, it's a bit painfull from scratch ([QTcpServer class](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html)), but several projects make it a bit easier: [QHttpServer](https://github.com/nikhilm/qhttpserver), [QtWebApp](http://stefanfrings.de/qtwebapp/)
4. If performance is your goal, I doubt you can achieve something significantly better (or just "better") without spending a lot of time on it. Namely to be able to handle a large number of request simultaneously in a fast way, a basic implementation will not be enough.

Comment: HI there. Thank you very much. You have really helped me a lot with your answer. I would love to send you a private message to discuss in a little more detail what i wish to achieve for you to be able to advise me weather it would be worth it or not. As far as this question both you and the person below have answered it really. I wish I could mark both as answers. For the simple fact there is more code below as an example ill mark that one as the answer. Hope your ok with that. But really thanks again

Comment: No problem, don't worry :). You can contact me on LinkedIn if you want to discuss it a bit, you'll find me easily.

Comment: Thank you. I just added you on linked in

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass QTCPServer. Set it up to listen on the port you want. This object will then get the requests and you can parse them and respond to them.

Something like this (partial code);

```
  #include <QTcpServer>
  #include <QTcpSocket>


  class mySuperNodeLikeServer : public QTcpServer
  {
      mySuperNodeLikeServer(QObject *parent);
      void startServer(int port);
      void readyToRead(void);
      void incomingConnection(int socket);
  }

 // in your .cpp file

 void mySuperNodeLikeServer::startServer(int port)
 {
     bool success = listen(QHostAddress::Any, port); // this starts the server listening on your port
     // handle errors
 }

 void mySuperNodeLikeServer::incomingConnection(int socket)
 {
     // a client has made a connection to your server
    QTcpSocket *client = new QTcpSocket(this);
    client->setSocketDescription(socket);

    // these two lines are important, they will direct traffic from the client
    // socket to your handlers in this object

    connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readToRead()));
    connect(client, SIGNAL(disconnect()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));

  }

  void mySuperNodeLikeServer::readyToRead(void)
  {
     QTcpSocket *client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();

     // you can process requests differently here. this example
     // assumes that you have line breaks in text requests

     while (client->canReadLine())
     {
        QString aLine = QString::fromUtf8(client->readLine()).trimmed();

        // Process your request here, parse the text etc
     }
  }

  void mySuperNodeLikeServer::disconnected()
  {
     QTcpSocket *client = (QTcpSocket*)sender();

     // clean up a disconnected user 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Ill try the code out later tonight and let you know if I get everything working.

Comment: HI there. I tried your solution and didn't have lots of luck, but im sure im doing something wrong (Its been a few years since i wrote c++)

Comment: post some code. I have written a couple of servers for specific tasks and I abstracted a bit out for the example above.

Comment: Hi there. Sorry i forgot to mention that i updated my question with the code

Comment: Sorry, i left the declaration for disconnected out of the header example. Add a line with "void disconnected(void);" in the header for the class.